# Unable to mount nfs share to /var/www in fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs

I am attempting to automount an nfs share on my server to my local machine using fstab. I have a few shares from the server that mounts on the local machine. I am sharing all the drives that is mounted on the server in the /media folder to /mnt/server on local machine. They all mount prefectly and works as expected. I also want to automount to the apache web server /var/www folder on the server. manual mounting works fine, but I am unable to make an automount work.
fstab for these mounts looks as follows:

```
server:/media    /mnt/server   nfs4             rw,_netdev      0 0
server:/var/www  /mnt/var        nfs4            rw,_netdev       0 0
```

I don't have much more info unless someone can point me to a log where I can find more info, the error that dolphin shows is `"An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: mount.nfs4: failed to prepare mount: Operation not permitted"`. I have tried to change the nfs server share path but same error as always.

My setup is server: Ubuntu 20.10 samba and nfs active,
workstation: Kubuntu 20.04 only nfs active.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error, I also use webmin to manage both server and workstation via the webui. to resolve I navigated to the disk and network filesystems module of webmin and edited the nfs share for the /var/www automount, in the settings for the share I set `Allow users to mount this filesystem` to yes and saved. then clicked on share in dolphin and it opened as the /media shares do. I did not have to do this for the /media shares so somewhat unsure of why this happened, if anyone can share some info it would be appreciated.

Thanks